# Security loopholes in adding 666 permissions to /var/run/docker.sock

Tags: sockets, security, docker, jenkins

I was not able to build my dockerfile via jenkins until I added 666 permissions to /var/run/docker.sock. Now, I understand that this is more secure than adding the 'jenkins' user to 'sudoers' list. HOWEVER,

1. Is there still a better way ?
2. What are the ways in which this extra permission could be used to my disadvantage ?

Answer (score 1):

> What are the ways in which this extra permission could be used to my disadvantage ?

You have given permission for any user on the machine to become root without any password.

> Is there still a better way ?

For Jenkins, you just need to run the following to give them access to the docker group so they can run docker commands. This will give the Jenkins user access to become root, so you'll want to be sure your Jenkins is secure or you do not care about users becoming root on this system:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker jenkins
```

Comment: Well, I did that earlier. However, JUST by adding the jenkins user to 'docker' group allows me to run docker builds FROM CLI when I am logged in as 'jenkins' user. This DOESN'T works when I try to build a dockerfile via jenkins. I get ...

Comment: "Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.32/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&session=8663f090dc5cb6fc1d517870132074ae5139fba7d63efc5fdd779a5ed51138fc&shmsize=0&t=oc9-ci&target=&ulimits=null: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied" error

Comment: I should have mentioned you need to restart the jenkins service after updating the group. If you run docker builds from inside of a build slave container with the socket mounted as a volume, then there's some more work to map gid from host to the container.

Comment: First of all, thanks for prompt responses! However, I would like to mention 2 things - 1) I had already restarted the VM after adding jenkins user to group 'docker'. It was after this that I got the results I have told you about above and 2) I am running both docker and jenkins parallely on a VM. Thanks for responding promptly again !!:-)

Comment: What are the permissions on the docker socket when you see the error? `ls -l /var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: Default permissions were srw-rw----

Comment: Please include the user and group of the socket too. Just to confirm, you are running the build and all these commands on the Jenkins master, not another build slave?