# Getting "docker: open .env: permission denied." when trying to pass a .env file to docker run

Tags: docker, env-file

I have no problems running the test "Hello World" image.

But when I try to pass the `--env-file` variable as part of my `docker run` command I am getting `docker: open .env: permission denied.`

I have tried granting full permissions on my .env file but not joy still.

The command I am running is `docker run --network host --env-file .env <IMAGE_ID>`

Any help appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix docker: Got permission denied issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957195/how-to-fix-docker-got-permission-denied-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Add the current user to the docker group by executing the below command

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Step 2: Change the permissions of docker socket which can able to connect to the docker daemon

```
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: is it safe to add 666 permission? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47183254/security-loopholes-in-adding-666-permissions-to-var-run-docker-sock

Comment: Yes @prakhar please study more on the context which BMitch has written. Thanks

Comment: I have tried this and still the same result. Permission denied

Comment: This would make sense if the problem were with the user being unable to connect to the Docker daemon, but that's not the error they report here.

Answer (score 0):

A clean reinstall of Docker fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this all day.
To solve this:
I removed snap version of docker.
and removed snap/bin from path
export PATH=$(echo $PATH | sed 's/:/snap/bin//')
and reinstall latest version of docker

make sure to run
which docker
to see if your docker is installed in the right folder.

For some reason snap installation of Docker can't read .envs but the apt-get installation of the "Docker Community Edition" can.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).